# remove mortar + cement board? or self level ontop? Bathroom Floor

Tags: mortar, cement-board, thinset

I have some mortar on a cement board on my bathroom floor it seems. I want to put luxury vinyl over this. Is my best bet removing the mortar + cement board and then redoing that process? or using some sort of self leveler ontop of this? This mortar seems really thick and hard to get to the cement board to take it off!

[image: Photo of Floor]

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You *might* want to [edit] this. Motor and Mortar are rather different. Likewise, put the picture inline (sun and mountains icon.) You're new to this site, but not to stackexchange, so we'll believe you can handle those yourself...

Comment: So a 2 barrel 327 is not normal on a bathroom floor?

Answer (score 3):

That mortar on the floor seems quite solid.
You can just pour self-leveling mortar on top of it.  It is the simplest way.  Plus it will also keep the whole floor intact.

Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the condition of the mortar, if it loose or chipping, you could (or not) apply a layer of self leveling cement.

Otherwise use a magnet to find the location of the screws that hold the cement board to the floor, to remove them.